# MySQL self join if null function

Tags: mysql

I'm learning through MySQL Ver.5.7.17, please clarify on my below query.

I have a table employees which contains employee ids and corresponding manager ids, but few employees do not have manager ids as they belong to manager roles.

The table columns are employee id, first name, last name, manager id. I have designed below self join query which gives me employees with manager ids but I am looking for additional details of manager (who are also employees) who do not have manager ids (null).

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMP_ID, CONCAT(E.FIRST_NAME,' ',E.LAST_NAME
) AS EMP_NAME, 
M.EMPLOYEE_ID AS MGR_ID
,CONCAT(M.FIRST_NAME,' ',M.LAST_NAME) AS MGR_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES AS E JOIN EMPLOYEES AS M 
ON (E.MANAGER_ID =M.EMPLOYEE_ID) ORDER BY MGR_ID
```

I tried with IF NULL function in query as below and got below error message.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL(M.EMPLOYEE_ID,'NO MGR') AS MGR_ID ,CONCAT(M.FIRST_NAME,' ',M.LAST_NAME) AS ' at line 2

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMP_ID, CONCAT(E.FIRST_NAME,' ',E.LAST_NAME) AS EMP_NAME, 
IF NULL(M.EMPLOYEE_ID,'NO MGR') AS MGR_ID
,CONCAT(M.FIRST_NAME,' ',M.LAST_NAME) AS MGR_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES AS E JOIN EMPLOYEES AS M 
ON (E.MANAGER_ID =M.EMPLOYEE_ID) ORDER BY MGR_ID
```

Comment: There is no IF NULL function in mysql,you are looking for NULLIF

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`. Also, I think you need a left join in order to get those records as well which don't have a manager:

```
select E.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMP_ID,
    concat (E.FIRST_NAME,' ',E.LAST_NAME) as EMP_NAME,
    coalesce(M.EMPLOYEE_ID, 'NO MGR') as MGR_ID,
    concat (M.FIRST_NAME,' ',M.LAST_NAME) as MGR_NAME
from EMPLOYEES as E
left join EMPLOYEES as M on (E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID)
order by MGR_ID
```